# How to create dataframes in a for loop with automatically generated dataframe names

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to automates process of creating dataframes as iam trying to do analysis of multiple spreadsheets in pandas. is there a way that a dataframe variable name can be auto-defined inside a for loop? in the example below, i defined 3 csv paths and i want to end up with 3 dataframes having names:
df1
df2
df3

```
csvpath= ("/home/file1.csv","/home/file2.csv","/home/file3.csv")

for i in range (1,4):
    dfi=pd.read_csv(csvpath(i))
```

Comment: Just put them in a list...

Comment: how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work...

```
csvpaths = ("/home/file1.csv", "/home/file2.csv", "/home/file3.csv")
dataframes = list()   # an empty list
for i in range (len(csvpaths)):
    dataframes.append(pd.read_csv(csvpath[i]))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are trying to achieve. But this is **not** recommended.

```py
csvpath= ("/home/file1.csv","/home/file2.csv","/home/file3.csv")

for i in range (1,4):
    globals()[f"df{i}"]=pd.read_csv(csvpath(i))
```

Instead use a list:

```py
csvpath= ("/home/file1.csv","/home/file2.csv","/home/file3.csv")
dfs =[]
for i in range (1,4):
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(csvpath(i)))
```